# How to get row id of database on clicking a list item in a custom ListView?

Tags: android, database, android-intent, android-listview

I have defined a custom itemAdapter class that populates my `ListView` from a database. My database has about 11 columns out of which my list displays only name, address and other relevant details. When i click on the list item, my app calls an intent and starts another activity which shows all the details for the database row which was clicked from the list. But i am unable to get the `rowid` to do this. My app always gives a runtime error and asks to `Force Close`. Below is a part of my `onCreate()`  method:

```
    ListView lv;
    //other parts of code

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
        long id) {
            listIntent = new Intent(garageFinder.this,list_detail.class);
            Cursor c= (Cursor)itemsAdapter.getItem(position);
            listIntent.putExtra("g",c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id")));
            startActivity(listIntent);
        }
        });
```

For retrieving the extras from intent i am using this:

```
    Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
    int id = bundle.getInt("g");
```

Well, i closed my cursor as suggested but some problems still persist. Below is the error log:

```
02-18 17:25:43.718: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-18 17:25:43.718: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer
02-18 17:25:43.718: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at car_app.garage.garageFinder$1.onItemClick(garageFinder.java:82)
02-18 17:25:43.718: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
02-18 17:25:43.718: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
02-18 17:25:43.718: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
02-18 17:25:43.718: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-18 17:25:43.718: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-18 17:25:43.718: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-18 17:25:43.718: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-18 17:25:43.718: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 17:25:43.718: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-18 17:25:43.718: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-18 17:25:43.718: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-18 17:25:43.718: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: On a first look it seems OK. Can you post the log of the force close

Comment: i posted d log which causes d problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
         public void GetMyRow()//call this method in onCreate()
         {         

         Cursor myDatabaseCursor;
         myDatabaseCursor=myDataBaseHelper.fetchMyRowId();
         startManagingQuery(myDatabaseCursor);
         }

        ListView lv;


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
        {
            Cursor c=myDatabaseCursor;
            c.moveToFirst(position);
            listIntent = new Intent(garageFinder.this,list_detail.class);
            listIntent.putExtra("g",c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id")));
            startActivityForResult(listIntent,Row_id_Request);
        }
    });
         public void onActivityResult(int resquest,int result, Intent intent)
          { 
            switch(request)
          {
               case Row_id_Request:
               Bundle bundle= intent.getExtras();
               int id = bundle.getInt("g");
               break;
          } 
       }
```

in your DataBase Class add the following code

```
       public Cursor fetchMyRowid()
       {
          return db.query(table_name,new String[]{My_Row_ID},null,null,null,null,null);
        }
```

Comment: Thanx. but the problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

> "Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed"

Looks like you are not closing your cursor. Maybe you should call `c.close()` before `onItemClick()` returns. (Depends where that cursor comes from.)

However, your code looks a little strange to me. If you are extending the Android [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html), then the `id` parameter passed into `onItemClick()` should already contain your row id. If not, there's a `getId(position)` function.

Comment: Can you tell me how to extend CursorAdapter?? The id parameter in onItemClick is always returning 0 as the value.

Comment: Actually I just use [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) -- no need to extend it as it already implements CursorAdapter -- and my ListActivity.onListItemClick() gets passed the id just fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error log its seems plainly to be the problem, that you don't close your database. Close the database when you start your activity or even better: close your DB in onPause and recreate it in onResume.
This should solve your problem according to the error log you posted.